# Ruby On Rails - how to clean database programmatically?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, controller

So rake db:reset clears the database, but how do I do that in a controller?

Comment: Why would you want this? Cleaning the database ain't usually a standard practice.
Do you mean, there will be a feature (say a link) when clicked should invoke the Rails Controller and it should clean the entire DB? I see serious security concerns with this kind of control. The DB-admins should rather manage this.

Comment: OK I searched for 2 days and didn't find that, I was searching for how to clear the database using the controller. But that answer says not to use rake commands in a controller. So how do I set up my controller to clear the database?

Comment: are you afraid they won't pay you?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be misunderstanding what a controller does. Check out the official Rail's [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html).

> Action controller is the C in MVC. After routing has determined which controller to use for a request, your controller is responsible for making sense of the request and producing the appropriate output.

Assuming you wanted to delete all the records for a particular model, you could do something like:

```
class ModelNameController < ApplicationController
  def delete_all
    ModelName.delete_all # This also accepts optional conditions.
  end 
end
```

Keep in mind if you want to clean the database, that isn't the job of the controller.